# Getting a COM+ component to work on a 2008 R2 server

Tags: vb6, com+

We've got some ancient COM+ components that we wrote long ago, that we're trying to migrate onto a VM. Currently they're running on a Windows 2003 R2 server, working fine.

But they're not working on a 2008 R2 server that the VM is. It appears as though we just can't "reach" them at all from the VB6 apps on the client machine. How can we proceed from this point? How can we diagnose this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You're not giving us very much information to go on.

You might be interested in these links:

[.Net COM+ Interop Part I](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19535/NET-COM-Interop-Component-with-Classic-ASP-Part-I)

[Debugging COM+ Applications Part II](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19663/Debugging-COM-Applications-Part-II)

Alternatively, you might find it easier to just install Windows 2000 as a standalone server on your VM, and run your application off of it.

Comment: I think we may have solved our problem. The Applications server role wasn't applied to that server. Once that happened, then it appeared to allow the COM+ components to work.